# Web scraping response in {{ }}

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request

I'm tying to scraping web page by nodejs (request or axios), push request. And response i'll got like this:

`<div class="some">
  {{ some }}
 </div>`

[Exampel response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLW5B.png)

How to scraping this 'some' val to value text?

Comment: Please include some code !

Comment: What's `{{ some }}`? Why is `{{ }}` there? Does the page use some form of template engine or a framework? Do you want to scrape `some` word literally or what?

Comment: @estus i think, site render view by twig framework

Comment: You need to know this for sure. Again, do you want to parse `some` word or the layout `{{ some }}` renders to in browser? You can't scrape the latter with request or axios.

Answer (score -1):

First, install these **npm** modules:

> npm i request request-promise cheerio

The key moment is [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) module that allows you to use jQuery on back-end.
Here is code sample that extracts text from the first found div tag.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request-promise')

request('https://google.com')
  .then(htmlResponse => {
    // Here you html comes
    // Lets assume that returned html is that follows
    htmlResponse = '<div class="some">{{ some }}</div>'

    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlResponse)
    const [firstFoundDiv] = $('div').toArray()

    console.log(firstFoundDiv.children[0].data);
    // {{ some }} is an output
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

P.S. Use any site url you need instead of *google.com*

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing it already. But response like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLW5B.png - this is main proble. tnx

Comment: for web-sited that are loading dynamically, look at Puppeteer's side
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer